# What is the proper way to scope OData methods to single controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes, odata

I have WebApi 2 controllers working side by side with single OData controller in the same project. Trying to set up needed routing configuration:

- all request to **/api** should be mapped to this ODataController
- all other requests should be directed to ordinary Web Api controllers

When I try to map **/api** route to OData contoller like this:

```
class WebApiConfig
{
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
  {
    configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "ApiOdata", id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Organization>("Organizations");
     configuration.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: "Api",
        model: builder.GetEdmModel());
   }
}
```

all method calls work fine both to Web Api and OData controller, but such requests like **/api/$metadata** do not work.

When I remove "API Default" route - requests to OData controller methods such **/api/Organizations** stops working (returning 404) but **/api/$metadata** begins to.

Detailed 404 error message:

```
<Error>
 <Message>
  No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:53576/api/Organizations'.
 </Message>
 <MessageDetail>
   No type was found that matches the controller named 'Organizations'.
 </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

What is the proper way to map all OData calls to single controller actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally ended up with custom routing conventions. Added class for it:

```
public class CustomControllerRoutingConvention : IODataRoutingConvention
{
    public string SelectAction(System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
    {
        if (odataPath.PathTemplate.StartsWith("~/entityset") 
            || odataPath.PathTemplate.StartsWith("~/unboundfunction"))
        {
            return odataPath.Segments[0].Identifier;
        }
        // Not a match.
        return null;    
    }

    public string SelectController(System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataPath odataPath, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (!odataPath.PathTemplate.Contains("$metadata"))
        {
            if (odataPath.PathTemplate != "~")
            {
                return "ApiOdata";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and use it in Register method of WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
  ...
  IList<IODataRoutingConvention> routingConventions =  ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
    routingConventions.Insert(0, new CustomControllerRoutingConvention());

    configuration.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: "Api",
        pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
        routingConventions: routingConventions,
        model: builder.GetEdmModel());
}
```

It's not perfect solution and does not serve every OData request (only metadata, entitysets and unbound functions, like "api/Organizations") but it's quite enough for working with clients like o.js and Simple.Odata.Client.
Also, it allowed avoid controller messing and bloating for my project.